# Updating listview when item selected on a spinner

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner

I am currently using this method to filter the result of the list. I have a spinner which displays data, I want the listview to be filtered with the selected data.

```
    String[] finalArray = new String[gameData.size()];
    finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);
      // finalArray contains the selection for the spinner
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, finalArray);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selection = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            for(String str: oldList) {
                if(str.trim().contains(selection))
                    gameData.add(str);
            }
            finalArray = new String[gameData.size()];
            finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

I assumed that `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)` would update the list once a selection has been made but it currently doesn't do anything.

```
    String selection = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();

    for(String str: oldList) {
        if(str.trim().contains(selection))
            gameData.add(str);
    }
```

What I did was set the selection into a string. I then check if `oldList` contains the String selection. I then go through the oldList to match the `selection` if it does, put them into a new list which is `gameData` (considered as the filtered result). That's when I convert it into an array and load it to the listview if it matches.

Comment: What does the line `finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);` do? It seems you are passing an empty array (finalArray) to the ArrayAdapter? Please show the content of `gameData`.

Comment: `gameData` is a list. I do some string splits before this code. The contents of `gameData' is converted into array which is `finalArray`. It is not an empty array.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Updated the question

Comment: Do you always add to `gameData`? Or any element can be removed from `gameData` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the adapter outside the `onItemSelectedListener` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` when spinner item is selected.

```
String[] finalArray = new String[gameData.size()];
finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);

// finalArray contains the selection for the spinner
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, finalArray);

// Set the adapter here
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO: Change the elements of finalArray here
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Check the `// TODO:` part.

You need to change the `finalArray` here. Once you're done with the changes in `finalArray`, i.e. new elements are added in `finalArray`, you call the `notifyDataSetChanged` to see the change effected in your list.

Comment: This still doesn't work. I've updated the question if it's any more help.

Comment: I've seen your updated code and my code segment should work. I'm adding more details anyway.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I've just tried it out and updated the code above. I'm not sure if i'm along the right lines but its still not updating.

Comment: finalArray is updating with the new data set right? Did you check that? And yes, `notifyDataSetChanged` takes effect only if there's a change in the list. You can try changing the size of the finalArray forcefully and check if it works

Comment: I've just checked, it is technically updating. It's just adding more values into the current list. As in the finalArray is getting added more values but the listview is not currently updating still

Comment: Okay, i've just added a clear list so the remaining ones left are the filtered ones. But as mentioned, it's not updating the listView.

Comment: `setOnItemSelectedListener` is called when you click on an item in your spinner right? Can you please check that? Put a `Debug.Log` on your item click to check if its working properly.

Comment: It's all working and updating now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to call listview.setListAdapter(null) or listview.removeAll() before setting the new adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
String[] finalArray = new String[gameData.size()];
    finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);
      // finalArray contains the selection for the spinner
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, finalArray);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selection = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            for(String str: oldList) {
                if(str.trim().contains(selection))
                    gameData.add(str);
            }
            finalArray = new String[gameData.size()];
            finalArray = gameData.toArray(finalArray);
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            arrayAdapter.addAll(finalArray);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Also, why do you convert to an array when [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)) accepts List also as a data parameter? For a List something of this form should also work for you:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, gameData);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selection = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            for(String str: oldList) {
                if(str.trim().contains(selection))
                    arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I've only been working with Java for just a week and somehow I had the thought that ArrayAdapters only take in arrays but thanks for making that clear.